# Zero RPS in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, throughput

I need to achieve below in Jmeter

68 RPS for 90 seconds, followed by zero RPS for 10 minutes and again 68 RPS for 90 seconds.

I can able to achieve this by giving 1 for start and end RPS (instead of 0), when i give start and end RPS as 0 Jmeter goes to hung state.

Can you please let me know how to configure this in Throughput shaping timer

Thanks,

Comment: if am not wrong you want to pause jmeter from sending requests? check this link http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action